# Use embedded argparse in Python3

Tags: python, argparse

I want to make a Python module that can be used both by command line and other modules.
Like that :

```
python3 Capacity.py arg1 arg2 arg3
or
>>> capacity.execByString("arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

I made a class to (with some researches) get the result of argparse within the code :

```
class ArgumentParserError(Exception): pass

class Parseur(ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, msg):
        raise ArgumentParserError(msg)

    def analyze(self, args):

        if type(args) is not list:
            args = args.split() # To work with a String

        try:
            result = self.parse_args(args)
            return True, result
            # Returns True and the namespace if OK
        except ArgumentParserError as err:
            return False, err.args[0]
            # Returns False and the error message if not OK
```

I use it like this :

```
class Capacity():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = Parseur()
        # Config the parser

    def execByArguments(*args):
        # Do the job

    def execByString(command):
        isOK, result = self.parser.analyze(command)
        if isOk:
            # Launch execByArguments with the rights args in result
        else:
            # Print error message
            print(result)

    def execFromCommandLine():
        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        # Launch execByArguments with the rights args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execFromCommandLine()
```

But there's 2 main problems and surely some I have'nt yet discovered :

- the args are not parsed correctly (doubles quotes for example) as the split function has the "spaces" separator
- using the -h flag close the program anyway

I'm convinced that making this another Parseur class is useless/not good and there's a workaround.
Launching the module via subprocess is not a good idea neither : I want to get the returned object in that case.
Can you help me to find a cool way to do what i want please ?
Thanks already.

PS : Write code on the online formular is such a pain ^^.

Comment: I'm curious: for what reason would you want to support `capacity.execByString("arg1 arg2 arg3")` rather than `capacity.execByString("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")` or `capacity.execByString(["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"])`?

Comment: `shlex.split` splits a string like a shell.  By default the `-h` Action displays the help and does a `sys.exit`.  If you don't want the exit, you need to either catch it in a `if/except` block, or omit it with `add_help=False` parameter.  You could then add your own `-h` as a `store_true`.

Comment: In fact, I get the String from Telegram, a msg app, and I just want to call the right capacity with the content of the message, with use of the polymorphism of the Capacity class children. And the argparse module is soooo useful I need to use it. Then, calling the module directly from command line is just bonus ! ^^

Comment: @hpaulj Oh ! That is useful ! I gonna test it right now..

Comment: @lial_slasher What do you mean by *embedded*? You can do `arg_parser.parse(shlex.split(input_string))`

Answer (score 0):

You are not far away. I would do it somehow like this:

```
class Capacity():
    def __init__(self, argv):
        # take over and store arguments (or process further parsing)
        self.parser = Parseur()
        isOk, result = self.parser.analyze(argv)

def argInputValidation(argv):
    #checking the command line arguments given by user
    #and returning valid argv, otherwise exit program
    #with an error message.
    return argv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Capacity(argInputValidation(sys.argv[1:]))
```